# Joomla 3.10.9 - edit User Account Details displays my login details

Tags: user

joomla back end editing user account details reverts to my user info.
I see the users info for a second then it switches to my user account details (superadmin).
The assigned user groups is correct.
Any suggestions?

As a test, I tried to edit a user, removing them from a group for example, the ID displayed was that of the user. I could not save, error message: Save failed with the following error: Username in use.

Comment: Is this a new, clean build? If not, are you suspicious of any newly installed extensions or recently deployed custom code?

Comment: No custom code. Build that has been in use for quite some time, stable, nothing changed except updates. Problem started after one of the joomla updates. Valid question you had, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a **browser plugin** running that changes the values.

Do you use the password manager **LastPass**?
If so, logout from LastPass and refresh the page. The real user data should be displayed without being replaced with your own user account data.

Comment: pe7er, you rock. That was it. lastpass. Mystery solved, thank you!